# System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument does not contain a definition for GetElementByID

Tags: c#

Can you explain why I am receiving this error?

```
    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement mainNav = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByID("home");
            mainNav.InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

Error 1

```
'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementByID' and no extension method 'GetElementByID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's `GetElementById`, with a lowercase 'd'.

Documentation is at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx

---

Side note: A Google search on `system.windows.forms.htmldocument` led me right to the documentation to check, and Intellisense should also have been able to tell you the right spelling. I do realize it sometimes takes an extra pair of eyes, though.

Comment: @AndrewBrigance: Seems extreme.  Maybe just a light slap to the face? :D

Comment: Like I said in my side note, sometimes it really takes extra eyes. Maybe it's just time for a break or more coffee?