# WPF displaying 'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementById'

Tags: c#, wpf, getelementbyid

Part of my WPF application has two text boxes for username and password. With a click of a button, the program should log the user into a website. The issue is that GetElementById is throwing up an error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementById' and no
>   extension method 'GetElementById' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

The code in question is this:

```
    private void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("AccountBarLogin").InvokeMember("click");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("QuickLoginEmail").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("QuickLoginPassword").SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("QuickLoginSubmit").InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

I have added a reference to System.Windows.Forms, as well as to MSHTML. What exactly needs to be referenced to prevent the GetElementByID throwing up this error?

Saw this: [System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument does not contain a definition for GetElementByID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126998/system-windows-forms-htmldocument-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-getelementby) but in this case it does not seem to be a typo.

Comment: See [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21466587/1136211).

Comment: Thank you Clemens, the information linked issue has solved it!

Answer (score -1):

This is not available in the WPF WebBrowser control.

You will need to use the WinForm WebBrowser control and add it to a WindowsFormHosted control.

Add a WindowsFormHosted to your page then in the code behind create the WinForm WebBrowser control.

XAML

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIn‌​tegration"
```

Code Behind

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
windowsFormsHost.Child = browser;
```

Comment: This is plain wrong. Take a look at the answer I've linked in my comment to the question.